# Discord Bot gets online but doesn't respond to messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
    ]
});


client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("messageCreator", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
      msg.reply("pong");
  }
})
client.on("message", Message => {
  if (msg.content === "hi") {
      msg.reply("hello");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Hi, im tryng learn how to make a discord bot for my server and i dont know much of js. I've been reading some tutorials but isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to listen to 2 message events, `messageCreator` and `message`.

The event `messageCreator` doesn't exist. You need to replace it with [`messageCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate).

The event `message` has been deprecated. (Also, you've named your message instance `Message` but you're referring to it as `msg`.)

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("messageCreate", (msg) => {
    if (msg.content === "ping") {
        msg.reply("pong");
    }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but still didint work